# Why android emulator running fast without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I wonder why android emulator is running fast after I close eclipse? Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipse + emulator uses a good amount of ram. If you runs only emulator then the ram usage of eclipse is free. So definitely you are getting more ram. so not only emulator, All application should run faster without eclipse.. This is just an hypothesis, I found no reasons other than that

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that the reason is that the logcat is not read anymore. Possible that if your connection to the emulator is slow the emulation gets slower.

IMHO the emulator is always slow even on a 8 core computer with 8 GB of RAM.